# Parsing part of xml file(blackberry)

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry

I want to parse an XML file that contains 150 records when displaying it takes a long time I want to display juste 10 records and the user choose when to display the others.
so how can i just parse a part of the XML document.
PS: i'm using Kxml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMParser`. It is up to you to finish parsing in a loop. Here are some links:

http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#5.1

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 0):

Since 150 records is not big, you can load the entire XML document into the memory using DOMParser and then use an XPath/XQuery processor (e.g., an XQuery processor, http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to query the DOM tree, read the number of records you want from the DOM tree and display them.